# php switch case in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, include, switch-statement

I am trying to generate switch from list of files in directory

I have directory tree

```
 ../pages/
          -home.php
          -about.php
          -service.php
          -contact.php

  ../system/
           -error404.php 

  -index.php
  -functions.php
```

And I want to generate switch statement in function open_page() in functions.php to include file from PAGES into index.php.

What I need to generate is this function in functions.php:

```
open_page($page){

    switch ($page) {

        case '':        require_once("pages/home.php");    break;
        case 'home':    require_once("pages/home.php");    break;
        case 'about':   require_once("pages/about.php");   break;
        case 'service': require_once("pages/service.php"); break;
        case 'contact': require_once("pages/contact.php"); break;

    default: require_once("system/error404.php");          break;

    }
}
```

My try:

```
//get all pages from dir PAGES
foreach (glob("pages/*.php") as $path) {

    $file = explode("/", $path);
    $filename = explode(".", $file[1]);

    $pages[] = $filename[0];
}

switch ($page) {
    case '': require_once("pages/home.php");
        break;

    foreach ($pages as $page){

        case '{$page}': require_once ("pages/"{$page}".php");
    }

    default: require_once("system/error404.php");
        break;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

index.php

```
<?php
    include 'functions.php';
?>

<html>
    <body>

        <div id="menu">
            <a href=index.php?page=home>Home</a>
            <a href=index.php?page=about>About</a>
            <a href=index.php?page=service>Service</a>
            <a href=index.php?page=contact>Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <?php
                open_page($_GET['page']);
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because he will afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer on how to do a loop in a switch but I believe you can solve your problem by doing this: You check to see if the file exists. If it does you load it. If not you load the error page.

```
function open_page($page = 'home') {
    if (empty($page)) {
        $page = 'home';
    }

    $file = "pages/{$page}.php"

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require_once($file);
    } else {
        require_once("system/error404.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to downvote because `$page` isn't really being legitimately checked.

Comment: Again, you are being pedantic.

Comment: @RobW At no point does the OP say that $page is coming from user-input so there may not be a need to sanitize it

Answer (score 1):

A switch is not required.

```
if($page=='')
  $page = 'home';
$filename = "/path/to/{$page}.php";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    require_once($filename);
} else {
    require_once("system/error404.php");
}
```

Comment: What if `$page` is `../../some-other-file.php`? There are other things that could go wrong by not checking `$filename` properly.

Comment: Jeez, it's an example, that's why I put /path/to/ . I think you are being pedantic for the sake of it.

Answer (score -2):

The logic is flawed for your `switch` block.

You could do something like this instead:

```
$page = basename($page);
if(empty($page)) {
  $page = "home";
}

if(file_exists("pages/{$page}.php")) {
  require_once("pages/{$page}.php");
else {
  require_once("pages/error404.php");
}
```

**Edit**: Notice how I used `basename` around the `$page` variable. This is fairly important so that your `$page` can't be something like `../../some-other-file.php`, for example.